# Bad pointers by blurring Mat from std::vector<int>: cv::Exception

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, vector, mat

I am new to openCV and have experimented for several hours but without success so I hope you can give me some advice. I am trying to detect circle centers in images as described here:
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/

I am using C++ in Visual Studio 10 on Windows XP and OpenCV 2.2.0.

My images come in `std::shared_ptr<CImg<double>>` format showing black dots on white background. Then I convert them to `std::vector<int> vecImagePx` of length 65536 (256 rows/columns) with data values between 0 and 255. I have verified that everything is ok.

Next, I convert the vector to a Mat, which is done correctly. I know this from looking at the jpg-file, also pointers to datastart and dataend and data are not shown to be bad pointers according to Visual Studio 2010 but seem to have valid adresses. Also, the Mat is not empty:

```
//[...]
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
//[...]
using namespace cv;
[...]

Mat tmpImage= Mat(vecImagePx, false).reshape(1, 256);
imwrite( "Image_0.jpg", tmpImage ); // Works fine
bool emptyImg=tmpImage.empty(); // Returns "false"
```

As soon, as I apply any filter or threshold, I get errors:

```
medianBlur(tmpImage, tmpImage, 3); // Would give error
threshold(tmpImage, tmpImage, 128, 255, THRESH_BINARY); // Would give error
```

Error Message:
**Unhandled exception at 0x7c812fd3 in ModulatedImaging.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0011bc14..**
Additionally, the pointers to data, dataend etc. are now `0.0000 <Bad ptr.>` according to Visual Studio.

However, creating a Mat from random values, using the same methods, works pretty fine. Nevertheless, assigning `tmpImage` to `R2` gives the same error as described above:

```
Mat R2 = Mat(256, 256, CV_8UC1);
randu(R2, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(255));
medianBlur(R2, R2, 3); // Works fine
threshold(R2, R2, 128, 255, THRESH_BINARY); // Works fine

Mat tmpImage= Mat(vecImagePx, false).reshape(1, 256); // Works fine
imwrite( "Image_0.jpg", tmpImage ); // Works fine
R2=tmpImage; // Works fine
medianBlur(R2, R2, 3); // Gives error
threshold(R2, R2, 128, 255, THRESH_BINARY); // Gives error
```

I have also e.g. tried the following conversion from `std::vector<int>` to `Mat`, but there the jpg.-image results in wrong stripes and the filters do not work as well:

```
cv::Mat tmpImage(256,256,CV_8UC1,&vecImagePx.front()); // results in wrong stripes
```

What can I do to avoid the error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I found the solution: The **data type** of `Mat tmpImage` is not correct for using the described filters! Using `int type=tmpImage.type();` and the table below I found out that the type of `tmpImage mat` is **CV_8UC3**. However, the type of `R2` is **CV_8U1**.

Converting the data type of `tmpImage` to **CV_8U1** using `tmpImage.convertTo(tmpImage,CV_8UC1);` solved all problems!

This is the table I used to assign the type integer to a certain data type:

```
*+--------+----+----+----+----+------+------+------+------+
|        | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C(5) | C(6) | C(7) | C(8) |
+--------+----+----+----+----+------+------+------+------+
| CV_8U  |  0 |  8 | 16 | 24 |   32 |   40 |   48 |   56 |
| CV_8S  |  1 |  9 | 17 | 25 |   33 |   41 |   49 |   57 |
| CV_16U |  2 | 10 | 18 | 26 |   34 |   42 |   50 |   58 |
| CV_16S |  3 | 11 | 19 | 27 |   35 |   43 |   51 |   59 |
| CV_32S |  4 | 12 | 20 | 28 |   36 |   44 |   52 |   60 |
| CV_32F |  5 | 13 | 21 | 29 |   37 |   45 |   53 |   61 |
| CV_64F |  6 | 14 | 22 | 30 |   38 |   46 |   54 |   62 |
+--------+----+----+----+----+------+------+------+------+
```